# a null constant in Python c extension

Tags: python, c, python-c-api

I am developing a python c extension
I want to have a constant for my module. If module name is module1 then the constant should be `module1.null`. When a user passes `module1.null` I want to perform a particular operation.
So what value should I give this constant. I cannot keep it to `Py_None` as when the user passes a `None` I want to perform a different operation from what is performed when he passes `module1.null`

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Several years ago, I went on quest to create the most useless object. My UndefinedObject cannot even be converted to a boolean value. From Python, the object can only identified via `id()` or `is`.

I just extracted the code from the large project so you will probably need to tweak it a bit.

```
/* The Undefined object is an attempt to make the most useless object possible.
 * It is intended to be used as a default value for a keyword argument that
 * could not be *reasonably* passed as a usable value. None is normally used
 * but None can be a useful value.
 *
 * Undefined does not support conversion to a boolean value so "if Undefined:"
 * will raise an exception. Comparisons are not supported, either. Hashing is
 * not supported so Undefined can't be used as a dictionary key. */

static PyObject *case_Undefined = NULL;

typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
} UndefinedObject;

static PyTypeObject Undefined_Type;

#define UndefinedObject_Check(v) (Py_TYPE(v) == &Undefined_Type)

static UndefinedObject *
UndefinedObject_new(PyObject *arg)
{
    return PyObject_New(UndefinedObject, &Undefined_Type);
}

static void
UndefinedObject_dealloc(UndefinedObject *self)
{
    PyObject_Del(self);
}

static int
UndefinedObject_bool(UndefinedObject *self)
{
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError,
                    "UndefinedObject does not have a boolean value");
    return -1;
}

static PyObject *
Undefined_richcompare(PyObject *self, PyObject *other, int op)
{
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError,
                    "UndefinedObject can not be compared");
    return NULL;
}

static PyObject *
Undefined_str(PyObject *self)
{
    return Py_BuildValue("s", "Undefined");
}

PyDoc_STRVAR(undefined_doc,
"The Undefined object can be used as a default value instead of None.\n"
"To minimize chances of using Undefined as useful Python object, it\n"
"is designed to be as unusable as possible:\n"
"  - Undefined cannot be a dictionary key\n"
"  - Undefined does not have a boolean value\n"
"  - Undefined cannot be compared to anything, even itself");

static PyNumberMethods undefined_number_methods =
{
    0,                              /* nb_add */
    0,                              /* nb_subtract */
    0,                              /* nb_multiply */
    0,                              /* nb_remainder */
    0,                              /* nb_divmod */
    0,                              /* nb_power */
    0,                              /* nb_negative */
    0,                              /* nb_positive */
    0,                              /* nb_absolute */
    (inquiry)UndefinedObject_bool,  /* nb_bool */
    0,                              /* nb_invert */
    0,                              /* nb_lshift */
    0,                              /* nb_rshift */
    0,                              /* nb_and */
    0,                              /* nb_xor */
    0,                              /* nb_or */
    0,                              /* nb_int */
    0,                              /* nb_reserved */
    0,                              /* nb_float */
    0,                              /* nb_inplace_add */
    0,                              /* nb_inplace_subtract */
    0,                              /* nb_inplace_multiply */
    0,                              /* nb_inplace_remainder */
    0,                              /* nb_inplace_power */
    0,                              /* nb_inplace_lshift */
    0,                              /* nb_inplace_rshift */
    0,                              /* nb_inplace_and */
    0,                              /* nb_inplace_xor */
    0,                              /* nb_inplace_or */
    0,                              /* nb_floor_divide */
    0,                              /* nb_true_divide */
    0,                              /* nb_inplace_floor_divide */
    0,                              /* nb_inplace_true_divide */
    0,                              /* nb_index */
};

static PyTypeObject Undefined_Type = {
    PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL, 0)
    "UndefinedObject",                       /* tp_name */
    sizeof(UndefinedObject),                 /* tp_basicsize */
    0,                                       /* tp_itemsize */
                        /* methods */
    (destructor)UndefinedObject_dealloc,     /* tp_dealloc */
    0,                                       /* tp_print */
    0,                                       /* tp_getattr */
    0,                                       /* tp_setattr */
    0,                                       /* tp_reserved */
    (reprfunc)Undefined_str,                 /* tp_repr */
    &undefined_number_methods,               /* tp_as_number */
    0,                                       /* tp_as_sequence */
    0,                                       /* tp_as_mapping */
    0,                                       /* tp_hash */
    0,                                       /* tp_call */
    (reprfunc)Undefined_str,                 /* tp_str */
    0,                                       /* tp_getattro */
    0,                                       /* tp_setattro */
    0,                                       /* tp_as_buffer */
    Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT,                      /* tp_flags */
    undefined_doc,                           /* tp_doc */
    0,                                       /* tp_traverse */
    0,                                       /* tp_clear */
    (richcmpfunc)&Undefined_richcompare,     /* tp_richcompare */
    0,                                       /* tp_weaklistoffset */
    0,                                       /* tp_iter */
    0,                                       /* tp_iternext */
    0,                                       /* tp_methods */
    0,                                       /* tp_members */
    0,                                       /* tp_getset */
    0,                                       /* tp_base */
    0,                                       /* tp_dict */
    0,                                       /* tp_descr_get */
    0,                                       /* tp_descr_set */
    0,                                       /* tp_dictoffset */
    0,                                       /* tp_init */
    0,                                       /* tp_alloc */
    0,                                       /* tp_new */
    0,                                       /* tp_free */
    0,                                       /* tp_is_gc */
};

/* End of UndefinedObject. */

/* Incomplete initialization code. *

    if (PyType_Ready(&Undefined_Type) < 0)
        goto fail;

    /* Create the singleton instance and add it to the module. */

    case_Undefined = (PyObject*)UndefinedObject_new(NULL);
    if (case_Undefined == NULL)
        goto fail;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Just create some new object. It doesn't need any methods, but it would be useful if comparison to anything else would result in false. Just make sure there's only one of them created at init time. That should do what you need.

Basically an equivalent to python code:

```
null = object()
```